# Piping with SSH and split the file

Tags: ssh, tar, split

Im using

```
tar zcf - stuff | ssh user@server 'cat > data.tar.gz'
```

Is there a way to split the file on transfer?

Something like this:

```
tar zcf - stuff | split -b 5G | ssh user@server 'cat > data-${part}.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command is called [`split`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/split.1.html).

```
tar czf - stuff | split -b 5G -d -f 'ssh server "cat >$FILE"'
```

This option is new in Ubuntu 12.04. With previous versions, `split` can only split to files, not to commands. The files can be named pipes, but organizing the commands to read from the pipes is cumbersome.

Without `split -f`, an easier approach is to forget about using a command. Mount the remote filesystem with [sshfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sshfs) instead, so that you can write to it as if it was a local file.

```
mkdir ~/net/server
sshfs user@server ~/net/server
tar czf - stuff | (cd ~/net/server && split -b 5G -d)
fusermount -u ~/net/server
```

You might be interested in a proper backup software such as [duplicity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/duplicity.1.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work.
And: sshfs is not installed on the server and I'm not the administrator...

Comment: @Andreas If FUSE is available (specifically, the `fuse` package, which contains privileged components), you can install SSHFS manually. It's a lot more hassle than a simple package installation, of course, so if you aren't the admin it's only worth doing it if you do nontrivial manipulations of remote files often.

Comment: On sshfs + duplicity also see https://serverfault.com/a/544026/203035